# Formula for AABCCBAABCCBAA sequence

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sequence

I am trying to create an Excel formula that, based on the year, will generate a weeknumber between 30 and 32. The pattern should be 30,30,31,32,32,31,30,30,31..etc

- 2019 31
- 2020 32
- 2021 32
- 2022 31
- 2023 30
- 2024 30

Is there a formula for this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=30+INDEX({1,0,0,1,2,2},MOD(A1,6)+1)
```

Comment: How would one go about it to create the number from a year?

Comment: @dreojs16, what do you mean? Update your original question to make it clearer.

Comment: What if I have a year in A1 and want to have the weeknumber in, say B1?

Comment: Well, you'd need to determine what is your startyear. So what year belongs to the very first 30 in your sequence of values? @dreojs16. Don't make us guess. Write a proper and clear question to avoid back-and-forth communication like this. I no assumed startyear is 1 and edited the answer accordingly.